# keep track of previous indexes after sorting

Tags: c, sorting

My problem is I need to keep track the present indexes corresponding to each inputted element and after sorting print with its previous respective indexes. I'm already done with sorting but i can't keep track the previous indexes of the inputted number.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap(int *xp,int *yp){
    int temp=*xp;
    *xp=*yp;
    *yp=temp;
}
void sort(int arr[],int n)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
            if(arr[j]>arr[j+1])
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
    }
}

void print(int arr[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("%d[%d] ",arr[i],i);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i,n,index;
    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int number[n];
    printf("\nInput numbers:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&number[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%d[%d] ",number[i],i);
    }
    n=sizeof(number)/sizeof(number[0]);
    sort(number,n);
    printf("\nSorted array: ");
    print(number,n);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Total number: 3
Input numbers:
4
2
3

Numbers are: 4[0] 2[1] 3[2]
Sorted array: 2[1] 3[2] 4[0]
```

Comment: Create an array of structures where you store the value with the present index. Then sort those structures. Another idea - create an array of pointers where each pointer points to the array element, in order. Then sort the pointers.

Comment: can you please help me with the code @KamilCuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved your problem by creating a `struct` which contains the actual value and the index of a given number given by the user:

```
typedef struct num {
    int index;
    int value;
} num_t;


void swap(num_t *xp, num_t *yp){
    num_t temp= *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}

void sort(num_t arr[], int n)
{
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
            if(arr[j].value>arr[j+1].value)
                swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
    }
}

void print(num_t arr[],int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d[%d] ", arr[i].value, arr[i].index);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i, n;

    printf("Total number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    num_t number[n];

    printf("\nInput numbers:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &number[i].value);
        number[i].index = i;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d[%d] ", number[i].value, number[i].index);
    }

    n = sizeof(number) / sizeof(number[0]);
    sort(number, n);

    printf("\nSorted array: ");
    print(number, n);

    return 0;
}
```